# INSERT e INNER JOIN juntos no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-insert

Olá é possivel utilizar o `INNER JOIN` juntamente com o `INSERT`?

Possuo uma tabela A com 3 colunas X, Y e Z e a tabela B com as colunas W, X e Y e preciso inserir na tabela A a coluna W da tabela B, teria como?
Estou tentando dessa forma porem n obtenho resultado :

```
INSERT INTO Categoria_cliente_teste  (planejamento) 
SELECT plano_orcamentario 
FROM Categoria_clientes 
INNER JOIN [ON cliente_fornecedor]
```

Comment: É possível e é algo bem comum se usar INSERT ... SELECT (dependendo do caso nem precisa do JOIN). O que tentou e qual o problema encontrado? EX: `INSERT INTO tabela A .... campo1, campo2 SELECT B.algo, C.algo FROM tabelaB JOIN tabelaC ON ...`

Comment: Sim, tem como fazer com o Inner Join, mas seria interessante exemplificar o que você quer fazer. Adicionar uma melhor descrição das tabelas e o código que já tentou.

Comment: coloque o que tentou na pergunta, para facilitar para quem ver depois

Answer (score 2):

Siim é possível!!

De acordo com sua descrição, criei o seguinte exemplo:

1- Criei um banco de dados com o nome "test"

2- Criei as seguintes tabelas:

**Tabela**: a

**Colunas**: x, y e z

-

**Tabela**: b

**Colunas**: w, x, y

Um exemplo de insert seria:
`INSERT INTO test.a ('y', 'z') SELECT b.x, b.y FROM test.b b;`

Você pode usar um inner join para selecionar os resultados que queira inserir normalmente, aconselho você dar um alias para a tabela da consulta, pois fica mais fácil para associar aos valores.

Com o JOIN:
`INSERT INTO test.a ('y', 'z') SELECT b.x, b.y FROM test.b b JOIN c ON c.y = b.y;`

:)